# Customize timeline Paper color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to customize this example of customized timeline:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Timeline from '@material-ui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineOppositeContent from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';
import TimelineDot from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineDot';
import FastfoodIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Fastfood';
import LaptopMacIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LaptopMac';
import HotelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Hotel';
import RepeatIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Repeat';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    padding: '6px 16px',
  },
  secondaryTail: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
}));

export default function CustomizedTimeline() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Timeline align="alternate">
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineOppositeContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
            9:30 am
          </Typography>
        </TimelineOppositeContent>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineDot>
            <FastfoodIcon />
          </TimelineDot>
          <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent>
          <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
              Eat
            </Typography>
            <Typography>Because you need strength</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineOppositeContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
            10:00 am
          </Typography>
        </TimelineOppositeContent>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineDot color="primary">
            <LaptopMacIcon />
          </TimelineDot>
          <TimelineConnector />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent>
          <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
              Code
            </Typography>
            <Typography>Because it&apos;s awesome!</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineDot color="primary" variant="outlined">
            <HotelIcon />
          </TimelineDot>
          <TimelineConnector className={classes.secondaryTail} />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent>
          <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
              Sleep
            </Typography>
            <Typography>Because you need rest</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineDot color="secondary">
            <RepeatIcon />
          </TimelineDot>
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent>
          <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
              Repeat
            </Typography>
            <Typography>Because this is the life you love!</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
    </Timeline>
  );
}
```

Ref: https://material-ui.com/components/timeline/#timeline

Do you know how I can set `Paper` background color to be green or red?

Comment: Do you want to change this color? https://nimb.ws/5cwQr4

Comment: Yes, this color.

Comment: Isn't this just a simple css question? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do like this?

```
paper: {
  padding: "6px 16px",
  backgroundColor: "green"
},
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-greider-lce2u?file=/src/App.js